# Wallpaper not displaying on screen? Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, background

I am trying to make a car game with tkinter and I was trying to set up a background image, which worked.

However, when I moved the code for the background into a function and then tried to use the function, it seemed not to work. I don't quite know what is going on so I would appreciate some help :)

I put all the code I was using for the background in a function called setting_up_bg() but when I call it, nothing works.

I have added an image at the bottom to show what it looks like when the code runs / what it is meant to look like (what it looked like before i put the code in a function)

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Menu, PhotoImage
import random
import time

window = Tk()

window.state('zoomed')

color1 = '#020f12'
color2 = '#ffd000'
color3 = '#ff8800'
color4 = 'BLACK'

def setting_up_bg():
    background = PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\acout\OneDrive - Activos Reais\Uni\Git\Tkinter\race_track.png')
    background_label= Label(window, image=background)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


def configure_window():

    window.geometry("800x600") 
    window.configure(background='#b3ffff')
    window.title("My Tkinter game yo - car go brrr")
    window.iconbitmap(default = r'C:\Users\acout\OneDrive - Activos Reais\Uni\Git\Tkinter\carro.ico')

    #setting up grid
    window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    window.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    window.rowconfigure(0, weight=7)
    window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    window.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
    window.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
    window.rowconfigure(5, weight=5)

    setting_up_bg()


#creates buttons and puts them on window
def create_menu():
    button1 = Button(window, 
                        background=color2, 
                        foreground=color4, 
                        activebackground=color3, 
                        activeforeground=color4, 
                        highlightthickness=2, 
                        highlightcolor='WHITE',
                        text='Start', 
                        command=Start(), 
                        height=5, 
                        width=13,
                        cursor='hand2',
                        font=('Fixedsys', 20, 'bold'))
    
    button2 = Button(window, 
                        background=color2, 
                        foreground=color4, 
                        activebackground=color3, 
                        activeforeground=color4, 
                        highlightthickness=2, 
                        highlightcolor='WHITE',
                        text='Leaderboard', 
                        #command=Start(), 
                        height=5, 
                        width=13,
                        cursor='hand2',
                        font=('Fixedsys', 20, 'bold'))
    
    button3 = Button(window, 
                        background=color2, 
                        foreground=color4, 
                        activebackground=color3, 
                        activeforeground=color4, 
                        highlightthickness=2, 
                        highlightcolor='WHITE',
                        text='Settings', 
                        #command=Start, 
                        height=5, 
                        width=13,
                        cursor='hand2',
                        font=('Fixedsys', 20, 'bold'))
    
    button4 = Button(window, 
                        background=color2, 
                        foreground=color4, 
                        activebackground=color3, 
                        activeforeground=color4, 
                        highlightthickness=2, 
                        highlightcolor='WHITE',
                        text='Exit', 
                        command=window.quit, 
                        height=5, 
                        width=13,
                        cursor='hand2',
                        font=('Fixedsys', 20, 'bold'))
    
   

    button1.grid(column=0, row=1)
    button2.grid(column=0, row=2)
    button3.grid(column=0, row=3)
    button4.grid(column=0, row=4)


configure_window()
setting_up_bg()
create_menu()

window.mainloop()
```

what it looks like:
[image]

what it is meant to look like:
[image]

Comment: Add `background_label.tkimg = background` inside `setting_up_bg`.